# Does Chrome use different event timings when the tab is in the background?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, jquery-events

I've noticed that Chrome plays this flawlessly when the tab is selected:

http://static.echonest.com/InfiniteGangnamStyle/

but breaks up in a consistent pattern when a different tab is selected. I'm curious why - it seems to imply that Chrome has a different event model or timings or priorities when the tab is in the background. There's nothing else running, the only change is the selected tab.

I've tried profiling this but without success - using extensions but they seem to be just as vulnerable to the change.

Of course, it might just be me. Assuming this is intended behaviour in Chrome, does anyone know why this happens and if it affects how I might write JavaScript to run properly in the background?

Answer (score 0):

i guess you are using setTimeout or seTinterval so when u switch other tab timer runs only 1 time per second

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=66078

Comment: It's not my site btw; it just happens to be a good example of the change in behaviour. Also, this issue was closed as fixed a year ago so it's highly unlikely this is the cause.